# How do you display the ID or auto incrementing 6 digit number in list NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Please provide a solution to this.
How do you display the ID or auto incrementing 6 digit number in list NewForm.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, the ID is allocated by SharePoint when the item is saved to the list.  So in the NewForm.aspx it is not yet available to display.

Comment: Thanks on you inputs could you let me how can you generate a field that gets autoincremented and make it to display in the newform.aspx

Comment: Can you perhaps explain more about why you need to see it in the NewForm?

Comment: It s like i need a field in newform which should get populated with 6 digit unique number when 'add new item' is clicked. How do you do that?

Comment: You could possibly maintain a separate list with your unique numbers in and use some jQuery to grab the latest, write a new row back with an incremented value etc but there is a lot of risk here depending on the concurrency of your list as if two users try to create new items at the same time then they will potentially get the same ID.  My suggestion would be to see if you can rework your solution to use the standard ID which is known to be unique.

Comment: yes, please advise me some around to display that ID in newform. some suggested me get the previous ID and display by adding 1. but if you would improvise on that it would be more helpful to me.

Comment: As I already explained, the ID is not allocated until the new form is saved to the list so the ID does not even exist while you are working with the NewForm.  If you were to somehow get the previous ID and increment it then what would happen if somebody else opened a new form at the same time?  They would both have the same ID so it would no longer be unique.  My suggestion is to come up with a different approach that does not need the ID so early in the process - that way you can use the standard ID after it has been allocated.  Much safer.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. i would work on  finding some alternate solution.